# How to disable alert message when refreshing a page which was submitted using POST?

Tags: php, post, modal-dialog, alert

I just want to know is it Possible to have those alert which says?

Confirm Form Resubmission !!

I am working on something that generates result. I don't want to annoy users by that alert box. Is there any way to remove those alert boxes.

There's another solution like posting to some other url and then redirecting to a page which is a GET url. It works fine for me. I just want to remove that dialog box. Is it possible?

Comment: You should only see that dialog box if you *refresh* a page that had been POSTed to.

Comment: its a browser feature, you cant do that. if you want to strict your form post then do human validations like captcha or some other manual calculations.

Comment: I didn't try to do something like that but you can try to play with onunload and similar events.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to POST to a URL, process the info there and then redirect to a new URL, for example with a header("Location: ") call. This way you also prevent a user from refreshing the page to resubmit your form.

Comment: That's what I don't want, i said. bro